# Zebra datepicker weekly calendar disable running weeks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, calendar, datepicker

I have used zebra datepicker weekly calendar. My week starts from monday to sunday. I wanna enable the dates only when the week is complete. So only when sunday(24 Aug 2014) ends date 18(Monday) have to be enable. Below is my zebra weekly calendar code.

```
$(function () {
    $(‘#weekdatepicker’).Zebra_DatePicker({
        format: ‘m-d-Y’,
        direction: -1,
        first_day_of_week: 1,
        disabled_dates: [''],
        enabled_dates: ['* * * 1'],
        show_other_months: true,
        select_other_months: true,
        onSelect: function (date) {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
        scope.$apply();
        }
    });
});
```

Kindly tell me solution. Thanks in advance